# DFP stop displaying ads until app is restarted

Tags: android, android-viewpager, google-dfp, adview

I'm using `PublisherAdView` in my App for ads integration. I have 3 ads per view and that is inside `ViewPager`. Ads are visible intially, but after visiting certain number of fragments inside `ViewPager`, ads stop working giving this in log:

```
I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
```

for all, until app gets restarted. I have also implemented `onPause()`, `onResume()` and `onDestroy()` methods for all publsihersAdViews.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context="com.expressdigital.express.fragments.NewsDetailFragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/news_details_swipe_to_refresh">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/news_details_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<FrameLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/news_details_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

        <!-- top ad layout-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/news_details_top_ad_view_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/news_details_screen_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_details_top_ad_view_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/news_details_title_left_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_details_title_right_padding"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/news_details_heading_text_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/author_name_and_time_passed_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_details_screen_title"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/author_time_layout_vertical_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/author_time_layout_vertical_padding">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_author_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_author_name_left_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_author_name_right_margin"
                android:textColor="@color/login_top"
                android:textSize="@dimen/news_details_author_name_text_size" />

            <com.expressdigital.express.utils.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:src="@color/divider_bottom" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_publish_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_time_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_time_horizontal_margin"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/login_top"
                android:textSize="@dimen/news_details_time_text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/news_description_top_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/author_name_and_time_passed_layout"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/news_description_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_description_top_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_content_horizontal_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_content_horizontal_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_details_content_vertical_padding" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_description_detail"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_above_mrec_ad"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            />


        <!-- bottom ad layout-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/news_details_bottom_ad_view_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_above_mrec_ad"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_details_bottom_ad_view_layout"
            android:id="@+id/extraSection">
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_description_detail"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_above_comments_layout"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details_comments_buttons_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/comment_buttons_layout_bottom_margin"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_add_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_add_comment_horizontal_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_add_comment_horizontal_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/comments_buttons_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/comments_buttons_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comments_buttons_horizontal_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/comments_buttons_horizontal_padding"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/news_details_comments_button_text_size"
                android:background="@drawable/add_comment_button_background"
                android:text="@string/add_comment"
                android:textColor="@color/read_all" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_read_comments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_comment_horizontal_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_comment_horizontal_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/comments_buttons_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/comments_buttons_vertical_padding"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/comments_buttons_horizontal_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/comments_buttons_horizontal_padding"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/news_details_comments_button_text_size"
                android:text="@string/read_comments"
                android:background="@drawable/read_comments_background"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/details_comments_buttons_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            android:id="@+id/view_below_comments_layout"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/details_next_story_layout"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_below_comments_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_next_story_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/details_comments_buttons_layout"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_padding"
                android:text="@string/next_story"
                android:textColor="@color/we_recommend"
                android:textSize="@dimen/we_recommend_text_size"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/details_next_story_heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/details_comments_buttons_layout"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_padding"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_left_padding"
                android:text="@string/next_story"
                android:textSize="@dimen/story_heading_text_size"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/next_story_icon"
                android:layout_weight="8"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/details_next_story_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            android:id="@+id/view_below_next_story"
            />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_for_detail_news_lazy_loading"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_blank_views_below_comment_layout_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_description_detail"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/news_details_blank_views_below_comment_layout_top_margin"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/news_details_bottom_progress_layout_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_bottom_progress_layout_height"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_below_next_story"
            android:id="@+id/detail_news_progress_bar"
            >

            <com.expressdigital.express.utils.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/express_loader"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                 android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_bottom_logo_padding"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_bottom_logo_padding"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_details_bottom_logo_padding"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/news_details_bottom_logo_padding"
                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/news_details_bottom_progress_layout_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_bottom_progress_layout_height"
                style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_we_recommend_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_for_detail_news_lazy_loading"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_padding"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/news_details_recommend_text_horizontal_padding"
            android:text="@string/related_stories"
            android:textColor="@color/we_recommend"
            android:textSize="@dimen/we_recommend_text_size"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/details_we_recommend_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/details_we_recommend_text"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/extraSection"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            android:id="@+id/view_above_details_ad_view"
            />

        <!-- ad type mrec layout-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/news_details_ad_view"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/view_above_details_ad_view"
            />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.8dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_details_ad_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/divider_bottom"
            android:id="@+id/view_below_details_ad_view"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/news_details_progress_layout"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/actionbar_size">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/actionbar_size">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/news_details_progress_layout_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_progress_layout_height"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <com.expressdigital.express.utils.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/express_loader"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/news_details_logo_padding"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/news_details_logo_padding"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/news_details_logo_padding"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/news_details_logo_padding"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="@dimen/news_details_progress_layout_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/news_details_progress_layout_height"
        style="@style/CustomProgressBar"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Possible its duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922978/ad-is-not-visible-not-refreshing-add-scheduling-ad-refresh-60000-miliseconds-f

Comment: @Shailesh in this thread ads are not visible all the time, but it is not the case ads are visible when we open the app.

Comment: Problem is you are try to load immediate ad in your fragment when you swipe your `viewpage`. Possible then please share your xml file where you can set your `ad`

Comment: Where is your ad `network` tag?

Comment: Ad are added in java class here is code snippet:                                                                                               mAdRequest = new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build();                                             topAdViewLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.news_details_top_ad_view_layout);
topAdView = new PublisherAdView(context);
topAdView.setAdSizes(AdSize.BANNER);
topAdView.setAdUnitId((String)CommonObjects.getSharedPreferences(context, "ad_id_top", ""));
topAdViewLayout.addView(mAdRequest);  // for all three different ads: top/bottom/mrec

Comment: @AndroidDev Please don't put snippets of code in comments (they're almost impossible to read). Please edit into the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ad in `viewPager` then  you have a couple of problems with your layout.

1. orientation is only relevant for a LinearLayout.
2. layout_alignParentBottom needs a boolean value not "top".
3. layout_weight is only relevant for a LinearLayout nor RelativeLayout.

Because you are using RelativeLayout, replace the banner example code with,

```
// Create the adView     
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID);     
// Lookup your RelativeLayoutLayout assuming it’s been given     
// the attribute android:id="@+id/ad"     
RelativeLayoutlayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ad);     
// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);     
// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad     
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

> Other Solution is

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
adView.bringToFront();
```

I hope you will get your solution. For detail check this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236169/use-an-adview-with-a-viewpager-and-a-pagertitlestrip)  and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105673/adding-admob-ad-to-relativelayout) .

Comment: AdView is used for Admob, and i have tried this approach but didn't work for me.